# Bug minimum time in UIDatePicker iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, date, uidatepicker, ios14

I am working in **UIDatePicker iOS 14** with below config:

```
 datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
 datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
 datePicker.minimumDate = Date() // 29 Dec 2020 at 14:00
```

When I change the time value and the value smaller than the minimum date (Ex: 29 Dec 2020 at 12:00), the DatePicker updated UI but the value still keeps the minimum date. It's working normally in iOS 13: the date picker returns the minimum value when the change value is less than the minimum value.

Is this the bug of UIDatePicker in iOS?

Comment: Minimum Date option  sets the minimum date for the date picker. You are changing the date to a value lower than minimum date, therefore picker will give you the minimum date value. If you see in the UI, picker must be coming back to minimum date if you are selecting a value below minimum date.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, looks like an iOS bug.